# QPushButton won't fire clicked slot (method of QObject)

Tags: qt, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt, pyside

I have a QObject, which works as a controller.
This QObject has a reference to a QPushButton.
This QOjbect has a method set to be fired upon QPushButton's clicked event.

Ex:

```
class MyController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyController, self).__init__(parent)

        self.some_ref = ....

        self.button = self.some_ref.button (returns QPushButton)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    # @Slot(type)
    def button_clicked(self):
        print 'button clicked: ', self.sender()
        # print 'button clicked (no sender req.)
```

Here, the button_clicked won't get fired.
I tried decorating it with `@Slot()`, `@Slot(QObject)`, `@Slot(type)`, `@Slot(str)`, `@Slot(int)` but still won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

If I use `..clicked.connect(lambda: self.button_clicked)` it of course works. So I assume this is a type mismatch but shouldn't `@Slot(..)` decoration have fixed it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the problem is that @Slot() is commented (have a # at the beginning), but this code works for me (it's in python 3, but just change the print line)

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setText("Test")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    def GetButton(self):
        return self.button


class MyController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyController, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = parent.GetButton() #(returns QPushButton)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    @Slot()
    def button_clicked(self):
        print('button clicked: ', self.sender())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    controller = MyController(window)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Hello! My codebase is a bit complex (many elements) and after reading your example carefully, I realised that I "broke" the QMainWindow parent referencing whilst moving around certain classes. Now it works. Thank you very much! I guess QObject referencing is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

May be could try the `released` signal instead of the `clicked` signal, because the clicked signal is emitted when the button is activated (i.e. pressed down then released while the mouse cursor is inside the button).

Or you could try the #method 2 of connecting the signals.

```
class MyController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyController, self).__init__(parent)

        self.some_ref = ....

        self.button = self.some_ref.button
        # method 1
        self.button.released.connect(self.button_clicked)
        # method 2
        self.connect(self.button, SIGNAL('released()'), self.button_clicked)


    def button_clicked(self):
        print "yipee it works..."
```

Comment: I tried old fashioned way of connecting them, both for clicked() and released() events but still won't work. I am really bewildered here. Thank you for your help.